# CSS remove the gap on inline-block elements between two child elements

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I just can't find the fix for this problem.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qog59a6b/

Here is the code:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>Box 1 - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>

<div>Box 2 - text text</div>

<div>Box 3 - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>

<div>Box 4 - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>

<div>Box 5 - There should be no margin between this box and the box number 2. This box should come just below box 2.</div>

<div>Box 6 - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
```

How can I remove the space between box 2 and box 5? I need box 5 to go up, just below box 2.

What's the CSS solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` to the parent element (`<body>` in your example). From here you can add `flex: 1 0 31%` to the div elements, as seen below:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 31%;
  margin: 1%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1 0 31%;
}

/* The parent */
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div>Box 1 - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>

<div>Box 2 - text text</div>

<div>Box 3 - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>

<div>Box 4 - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>

<div>Box 5 - There should be no margin between this box and the box number 2. This box should come just below box 2.</div>

<div>Box 6 - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
```

Note that the 31% is relative to the `width`.

Comment: That won't remove the space. It will fill the height box to became like the others... That's not what I want...

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `margin: 1%;` declares margin on all four sides of the div. Instead use `margin: 0% 1%;` which only specifies 1% margin on the left and right.

Edit ~ use `vertical-align: bottom;` on the second div.

```css
.contain>div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: calc(100%/3);
  margin: 1%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: max-content;
}

.contain>div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.contain {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contain>div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.contain:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 845px) {
  .contain:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(2) {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 115px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 698px) {
  .contain:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(2) {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contain">
    <div>Box 1 - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
    <div>Box 2 - text text</div>
    <div>Box 3 - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contain">
    <div>Box 4 - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
    <div>Box 5 - There should be no margin between this box and the box number 2. This box should come just below box 2.</div>
    <div>Box 6 - text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You did not understand the problem. Leave the margin or let it there. I don't talk about margin. I am talking about the gap between box 2 and box 5.

Comment: @Andrei See edits.

Comment: Still not a solution. I don't want box 2 to go down, but the box 5 to go up...

Comment: @Andrei See edits - probably your best bet with the requirements of all children having `inline-block`. Unless you want to completely restructure your HTML.